# DataGridView exception using double buffering

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview

I am running into some issues using double buffering with the C# .NET DataGridView when double buffering is enabled.  Previously I never had an issue in my code but I have added the following line:

```
            typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, dataGridView1, new object[] { true });
```

This resulted in a nice performance boost and has been running on a lot of computers with no issues.  However I received a message from someone that after 30 or 40 minutes he gets the following error:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowHeaderCell.PaintPrivate(Graphics 
 graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex, 
 DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState, Object formattedValue, 
 String errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
 DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts 
 paintParts, Boolean computeContentBounds, Boolean computeErrorIconBounds, 
 Boolean paint)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowHeaderCell.Paint(Graphics graphics, 
 Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex, 
 DataGridViewElementStates cellState, Object value, Object formattedValue, 
 String errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
 DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts 
 paintParts)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.PaintWork(Graphics graphics, 
 Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, Int32 rowIndex, 
 DataGridViewElementStates cellState, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, 
 DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts 
 paintParts)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.PaintHeader(Graphics graphics, 
 Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, 
 DataGridViewElementStates rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean 
 isLastVisibleRow, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle 
 clipBounds, Rectangle rowBounds, Int32 rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates 
 rowState, Boolean isFirstDisplayedRow, Boolean isLastVisibleRow)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintRows(Graphics g, Rectangle 
 boundingRect, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintGrid(Graphics g, Rectangle 
 gridBounds, Rectangle clipRect, Boolean singleVerticalBorderAdded, Boolean 
 singleHorizontalBorderAdded)
 at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, 
 Int16 layer)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
 at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, 
 IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)**strong text**
```

I have added the following to the code as an event handler for the OnPaint event for the dataGridView

```
    private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

I can only try and see if it works.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to repaint a null cells in the header row.  Do you test for null in your code?

Comment: There is a this.dataGridView1.DataError += this.dataGridView1_dataError; error handler that does the following...e.ThrowException = false;  The thing is this code worked for several years with thousands of users.  It is only by adding the double buffering that it seems that an issue arose.

Comment: I'm not sure.  You should always check for null as well with DGV the row count is > 0.  I suspect a null column exists (may be after a column was deleted) that is causing an issue.  The may be an issue in the database where the data is originating.

Comment: DoubleBuffering may expose an older error by changing the times needed for repaint.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right.  The thing is that this code has multiple threads so it is not easy to track this down.  However I have added a OnPaint event.  Please see above

Comment: The OnPainbt handler made no difference.